# Consistent AutoHotkey crashes

Tags: autohotkey

all
I've been using AutoHotkey to perform a number of batch processes at work.  It's going pretty well, but I keep running into an issue.  The scripts (more than one, doing very different things) will all crash after about 4 hours of running.  It's pretty consistent with the time, but only kind of consistent with the location in the program where it's running.
I'm not getting an error message.  The script will just stop, and when I try to open it up to see the last line, the program closes without any info.
I know it's vague, but any ideas what may be happening?

Edit: added Event Viewer data.  Two other crash events were almost identical.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-10-11T04:20:51.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>11519</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>My Computer</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>CDR to CGM-PDF 3-0-1.exe</Data> 
  <Data>1.1.11.2</Data> 
  <Data>51f4589f</Data> 
  <Data>CDR to CGM-PDF 3-0-1.exe</Data> 
  <Data>1.1.11.2</Data> 
  <Data>51f4589f</Data> 
  <Data>c00000fd</Data> 
  <Data>00000000000ca117</Data> 
  <Data>1c44</Data> 
  <Data>01cec61d2e612892</Data> 
  <Data>C:\CDR to CGM-PDF 3-0-1.exe</Data> 
  <Data>C:\CDR to CGM-PDF 3-0-1.exe</Data> 
  <Data>82958232-322c-11e3-ab1f-d067e5491d83</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: You could have a look at memory usage through the windows task mgr or check the windows Event viewer. Have you tried to write some key debugging data like counters into a debugging file after each loop in your batch file? This might give you a hint as to the state of the program just before it crashes and to see if all 4 scripts crash for a similar reason. I personally think that time is not the real issue but something like memory or variable size (integer up to 32767) and then flipping to negative.

Comment: I got the following info from the Event Viewer.  It's all Greek to me...

Comment: I posted a portion of the script to a different site, and the difference between "goto" and "gosub" was pointed out to me.
By copy/replacing the gosub with goto, the program ran consecutive nights without a crash.

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/30042-run-ahk-scripts-with-less-half-or-even-less-memory-usage/